# Esconder Ion-tabs Ionic 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Galera estou com um problema em relação as tabs do aplicativo. A aplicação que estou desenvolvendo possui uma tela de chat e nessa tela quero esconder as tabs. Já tentei usar `$ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(false);` a tabs realmente fica com o display:none porém uma barra branca fica no lugar dessa tabs. Alguem sabe alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable" ng-if="!hidebars">
```